# apex:repeat render as pdf cant format based on css tags for table or td or th or span

Tags: css, pdf, renderas, getcontentaspdf, apexpage

```
.bPageBlock .pbBody table {
    min-width: 90% !important;
    max-width: 90% !important;
    width: 90% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
  }
.bPageBlock .pbBody td {
    width: 45% !important;
    min-width: 90% !important;
    max-width: 90% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    padding-left:  50px;
    padding-top:  15px;
  }
.bPageBlock .pbBody th {
    width: 45% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
  }
.bPageBlock .pbBody span{
    width: 45% !important;
    max-width: 45% !important;
  }
```

this is my css for a visualforce page that prints as pdf.

I am able to print normal apex:outputlabels in proper tables and the CSS is consistant.

But, If i have an apex:outputlabel inside an apex repeat tag, then i cant format the table and it comes up very very weirdly.
[image]
Where as on a normal apex:outputlabel which is rendered as a table. the table tags seem to work.

I want to make sure the value never increase more than 45% of the page, if they do they have to wrap, which html would do automatically based on width.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your markup is formatted but there are times with apex component tags are overkill.

Simply use

`<label for="ELEID">{![var].[value|api name]}</label>`